# quickblox few ios push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

When I sending `push` notificiations via `quickblox` everything works fine. But when I have more than `3` messages on my phone instead of normal message there is `"You have X new messages"`.
Is there a way to change it to my `message text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

Go to https://admin.quickblox.com, Chat, Alerts and configure there your push payload

More info here

http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Alerts

Comment: Thank you! It works!
"automatic push notifications for offline user" its very confusing option...